# JavaScript and Closures When It Comes to Outer Variables

Tags: javascript, variables, reference, closures

I've been reading a book about JavaScript and the author has been touching the subject of closures for a few pages. On one page, he shows the following example:

```
function wrapElements(a) {
  var result = [], i, n;
  for (i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
    result[i] = function() { return a[i]; };
  }
  return result;
}

var wrapped = wrapElements([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]);
var f = wrapped[0];
```

Now, he says that one might expect **f();** to return *10*, but it actually returns *undefined*.

Here's what he says:

> The bug in the program comes from the fact that the programmer
>   apparently expected the function to store the value of *i* at the time
>   the nested function was created. But in fact, it contains a reference
>   to *i*. Since the value of i changes after each function is created, the
>   inner functions end up seeing the final value of *i*. [...] Since each 
>   iteration of the loop increments *i* until it runs off the end of the
>   array, **by the time we actually call one of the closures, it looks up
>   index 5 of the array and returns *undefined*.**

But I just can't get my head around his explanations. I've read again his previous explanations about closures (and think I understand them -- but obviously, it seems like I don't) and I've searched for more information on closures on the Internet. I stil can't understand why **f();** would return *undefined*.

Wouldn't the anonymous function be created and called at each iteration of the loop; and therefore, wouldn't it look up all indexes and not just index 5? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: no - the function is not called in the loop.

Comment: If the function inside the loop was an IIFE it would work, because the function would be called in loop scope at each iteration, e.g. `result[i] = (function(index) { return a[index]; })(i);`

Answer (score 2):

All the little functions created in the loop share that common variable `i`. What's the value of `i` when the `for` loop finishes? `5`.

When the functions are called, `i` is *still* `5`, and `a[5]` is `undefined`.

Here's the loop that creates the functions:

```
  for (i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
    result[i] = function() { return a[i]; };
  }
```

Each function created contains a reference to `i`, and means "return the array element corresponding to the current value of `i`", where *current* means current at the time the function is actually *called*.  JavaScript doesn't retain some "frozen" state for such functions, it retains the actual scope from the enclosing function. In that scope, the variable `i` is still its same old jolly self, and will be `5` whenever any of the functions created in the loop inquire as to its value.